# Excel count unique values if second criteria is also satisfied

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I currently have a formula to count all unique values of a range, however I would like to expand this count all unique values, if a second column meets a second requirement, for example.

```
      A        B
1  Name     Location
2  Tim      Onsite
3  Tim      Onsite
4  Ben      Offsite
5  Lisa     Onsite
```

In this instance the unique values of Name will return 3, for that I am using

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A5,A2:A5&""))
```

However when I try to use a `COUNTIFS` it always returns an error.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A5,A2:A5&"", B2:B5, "Onsite"))
```

Any ideas how to achieve this, so from my sample data, counting `Onsite` would return 2, (3 unique values, 2 of them satisfying the onsite criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bit more conversion:

`=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A5,A2:A5&"", B2:B5, "Onsite"),0))`

This is an array formula, so after inserting you need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Answer (score 0):

Spill functions make this a bit easier

=UNIQUE(IFS(“onsite”=locationRange,nameRange))

I’d put an IFNA() around it just to be safe.